# Combining Similar Lines XML

Tags: xslt, sum, rows

I have an XML record that have repeating unique ID's but would like to combine all similar ID's into 1 record, concat the reference fields and summing up the amount field.

The XML looks like this:

```
<root>
<row>
    <F01>123456</F01>
    <F02>ABC Company</F02>
    <F03>0</F03>
    <F04>47582736</F04>
    <F05>151.12</F05>
</row>
<row>
    <F01>123456</F01>
    <F02>ABC Company</F02>
    <F03>0</F03>
    <F04>47643792</F04>
    <F05>191.09</F05>
</row>
<row>
    <F01>123456</F01>
    <F02>ABC Company</F02>
    <F03>0</F03>
    <F04>47643793</F04>
    <F05>95.32</F05>
</row>
<row>
    <F01>223344</F01>
    <F02>DK Corp</F02>
    <F03>0</F03>
    <F04>36819319</F04>
    <F05>138.87</F05>
</row>
<row>
    <F01>223344</F01>
    <F02>DK Corp</F02>
    <F03>0</F03>
    <F04>36827362</F04>
    <F05>9.98</F05>
</row>
<row>
    <F01>223344</F01>
    <F02>DK Corp</F02>
    <F03>0</F03>
    <F04>36834497</F04>
    <F05>79.87</F05>
</row>
<row>
    <F01>113964</F01>
    <F02>Direct Company</F02>
    <F03>0</F03>
    <F04>1771929</F04>
    <F05>400.07</F05>
</row>
<row>
    <F01>113964</F01>
    <F02>Direct Company</F02>
    <F03>0</F03>
    <F04>1766940</F04>
    <F05>111.52</F05>
</row>
<row>
    <F01>113964</F01>
    <F02>Direct Company</F02>
    <F03>0</F03>
    <F04>1810269</F04>
    <F05>112.48</F05>
</row>
<row>
    <F01>113964</F01>
    <F02>Direct Company</F02>
    <F03>0</F03>
    <F04>1618234</F04>
    <F05>60.76</F05>
</row>
<row>
    <F01>113964</F01>
    <F02>Direct Company</F02>
    <F03>0</F03>
    <F04>1771923</F04>
    <F05>2829.19</F05>
</row>
```

I want to make it look like this:

```
<root>
<row>
    <F01>123456</F01>
    <F02>ABC Company</F02>
    <F03>437.53</F03>
    <F04>47582736, 47643792, 47643793</F04>
    <F05>151.12</F05>
</row>
<row>
    <F01>223344</F01>
    <F02>DK Corp</F02>
    <F03>228.72</F03>
    <F04>36819319, 36827362, 36834497</F04>
    <F05>138.87</F05>
</row>
<row>
    <F01>113964</F01>
    <F02>Direct Company</F02>
    <F03>3514.02</F03>
    <F04>1771929, 1766940, 1810269, 1618234, 1771923</F04>
    <F05>400.07</F05>
</row>
```

I think I may know how to concat F04 but don't know how to sum up F05 and put that value in F03.  F01 is the unique ID that should determine what to keep together.

Comment: What happened to `<F05>151.12</F05>` in the input for `ABC Company`?  It does not appear in the output, should it?

Comment: Please clarify. You want to collect all `row` elements with the same value for their child `F01` into a single `row` element. It looks like you want to keep the *first* occurrence of `F02`, `F03`, and `F05`; and combine all the values for `F04` into a list separated by commas. Is that right? Or do you want *all* the different values of the children collected as a list? Or perhaps you haven't thought this through at all?

Comment: How do you decide what must be the contents of the `F05` element? Please, *edit* the question and explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**When this XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="kRowByF02" match="row" use="F02"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <root>
      <xsl:apply-templates
        select="row[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kRowByF02', F02)[1])]"/>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="F03">
     <F03>
       <xsl:value-of
         select="sum(key('kRowByF02', preceding-sibling::F02)/F05)" />
     </F03>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="F04">
    <F04>
      <xsl:apply-templates
        select="key('kRowByF02', preceding-sibling::F02)/F04/text()"/>
    </F04>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="F04/text()">
    <xsl:if test="not(position() = 1)">, </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...is applied to the provided XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <row>
    <F01>123456</F01>
    <F02>ABC Company</F02>
    <F03>0</F03>
    <F04>47582736</F04>
    <F05>151.12</F05>
  </row>
  <row>
    <F01>123456</F01>
    <F02>ABC Company</F02>
    <F03>0</F03>
    <F04>47643792</F04>
    <F05>191.09</F05>
  </row>
  <row>
    <F01>123456</F01>
    <F02>ABC Company</F02>
    <F03>0</F03>
    <F04>47643793</F04>
    <F05>95.32</F05>
  </row>
  <row>
    <F01>223344</F01>
    <F02>DK Corp</F02>
    <F03>0</F03>
    <F04>36819319</F04>
    <F05>138.87</F05>
  </row>
  <row>
    <F01>223344</F01>
    <F02>DK Corp</F02>
    <F03>0</F03>
    <F04>36827362</F04>
    <F05>9.98</F05>
  </row>
  <row>
    <F01>223344</F01>
    <F02>DK Corp</F02>
    <F03>0</F03>
    <F04>36834497</F04>
    <F05>79.87</F05>
  </row>
  <row>
    <F01>113964</F01>
    <F02>Direct Company</F02>
    <F03>0</F03>
    <F04>1771929</F04>
    <F05>400.07</F05>
  </row>
  <row>
    <F01>113964</F01>
    <F02>Direct Company</F02>
    <F03>0</F03>
    <F04>1766940</F04>
    <F05>111.52</F05>
  </row>
  <row>
    <F01>113964</F01>
    <F02>Direct Company</F02>
    <F03>0</F03>
    <F04>1810269</F04>
    <F05>112.48</F05>
  </row>
  <row>
    <F01>113964</F01>
    <F02>Direct Company</F02>
    <F03>0</F03>
    <F04>1618234</F04>
    <F05>60.76</F05>
  </row>
  <row>
    <F01>113964</F01>
    <F02>Direct Company</F02>
    <F03>0</F03>
    <F04>1771923</F04>
    <F05>2829.19</F05>
  </row>
</root>
```

**...the wanted result is produced:**

```
<root>
  <row>
    <F01>123456</F01>
    <F02>ABC Company</F02>
    <F03>437.53</F03>
    <F04>47582736, 47643792, 47643793</F04>
    <F05>151.12</F05>
  </row>
  <row>
    <F01>223344</F01>
    <F02>DK Corp</F02>
    <F03>228.72</F03>
    <F04>36819319, 36827362, 36834497</F04>
    <F05>138.87</F05>
  </row>
  <row>
    <F01>113964</F01>
    <F02>Direct Company</F02>
    <F03>3514.02</F03>
    <F04>1771929, 1766940, 1810269, 1618234, 1771923</F04>
    <F05>400.07</F05>
  </row>
</root>
```

This is a classic grouping problem that, in the case of XSLT 1.0, uses [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html).

Comment: **Why the downvote? My output and the OP's requested output are 100% identical.**

Comment: I know it's been awhile but this helped and thanks to all those who replied.  I get these projects once in awhile and XSL/XML is not my forte.